# How to convert a text file to a numpy file

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to convert a textfile to a numpy file, my text file contains in each line a ciphertext:

```
a3140be40735f9f1865aa6b1b32b5667
23167dd91052ae65c5f27621d6e856a2
4d741dd44c079b12ff657e56eb9b2e0b
fc6a86ee980ee0fe36e48a65a6200053
86ce0634c82e6a3e049d76f62b4ff874
a3fbf406a651f41f015aee7e3452c4a3
7b7b1b6b8f0df7800c0495a1d72a3b14
2563cbbcce33a2097bdd017f89cff905
bd0f6cc7aae9ef7301183a6d3f855688
64d0470ec6bb72a3360cfa287c304eb5
598950560b06d10da657e0aab9a36c0e
df80c520099f1cb2605bf6780e000073
a0ae5abcd586de81093be28bc7929ef9
dcf021f46d6e12594aefb82185351b60
b6e332198239c0cc4d05f0d5a304a0b0
ecfae7851dce471b8cdb0f2c91822f9e
9a9e3f9f7b98f375f2b6a2eb008d1b17
173f5c6958a265e0bb00829e9facc0c5
```

My file contains 203860 lines. I need to put each line in one table, than put all tables in one big table: This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
In_path= r'Y:\Third_Traces\TextFiles\Ciphertexts_In.txt'
Out_path= r'Y:\Third_Traces\NumpyFiles\Ciphertexts_Out.npy'
all_arrays = []
with open(In_path, "r") as In_f:
    #all_arrays = [[l[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(l.strip()),2)] for l in In_f]
    #all_arrays=map(int,arrays)
    all_arrays = [[int(l[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0, len(l.strip()), 2)] for l in In_f]
    print (all_arrays)   
    with open(Out_path, "wb") as Out_f:
        np.save(Out_path, all_arrays)
data = np.load(Out_path)
print (data)
```

I expect to find a file with a shape of (203860L, 16L), but I found that is(1L, 3363690L), I don't know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `all_arrays` is just a plain python list of lists. Change this line

`all_arrays = [[int(l[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0, len(l.strip()), 2)] for l in In_f]`

to

`all_arrays = np.array([[int(l[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0, len(l.strip()), 2)] for l in In_f])`

so that it is a numpy array before saving it into a file. The shape should then be preserved.